# What the fastest way to convert Html to Pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf, pechkin

I have some "big" html files 4Mb+.

Then i convert one file to PDF via Pechkin ([.NET Wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf static DLL](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin)) I can safely go to sleep about 3-5 minutes.

Output PDF has 2Mb+ and about 500 pages inside.

```
var html = "...html...";
var data = HtmlToPdf2(res);
Console.WriteLine("HtmlToPdf2 done: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

...

```
private static byte[] HtmlToPdf2(string html)
{
    var pechkin = new SimplePechkin(new GlobalConfig());
    var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                            .SetLoadImages(true)
                            .SetZoomFactor(1.5)
                            .SetPrintBackground(true)
                            .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                            .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                            ,html);
}
```

My stopwatch say:

```
Start: 00:00:00.0007693
TransformXMLToHTML done: 00:00:03.6661490
HtmlToPdf2 done: 00:03:50.7784590
WriteAllBytes done: 00:03:50.7871326
```

My users will cry when they wait so long.

Comment: What goal would you expect and why ?

Comment: Have you tried passing the raw html to the wkhtmltopdf (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) command line on your machine and obtained comparable results? You could write a Powershell script to wrap this in a timer as well.

Comment: Vash - Damian, i expect something about 1, maybe 2 minutes.

Comment: Kyle B., i will try now. thanks

Comment: Why are you converting a HTML page to a PDF file? If a user wants to print it as PDF, they can use a PDF printer

Comment: Who the heck sent that close vote? It's a perfectly valid question. Also, seconding @KyleB.'s suggestion. If the results are close, then maybe there's no way to optimize it. However, if passing it to the command line has faster results, I suggest using that instead.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is not very accurate while rendering HTML pages , I found there were some issues for rendering at higher Resolutions.  If accuracy is not your concern , I would definitely recommend you to use Wkhtmltopdf ..

Comment: Chris Marisic, no, i don't show html for user. User put xml to my service, a transform it to html for printing.

Comment: Kyle B., yep! nice result.
#echo %date% %time%
07.09.2014 20:51:04,84

#wkhtmltopdf.exe input.html output.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done

#echo %date% %time%
07.09.2014 20:51:33,36

next step - understand how to use in c#

Comment: OK guys, I will use a temporary solution, using the launch wkhtmltopdf.exe using Process()

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a 500 page PDF in 3-5 minutes is quite reasonable.  Maybe this can be pushed into a batch job, allowing the users to do something else for a while?

Comment: Is's sad way, but if i don't resolve this problem, ofcourse, I'll have to go that way. Thanks!